# How do I use variable on DateTime.AddHours()

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

I have test variable from database(int). I need to use this variable on DateTime.AddHours.

I tried:

```
DateTime.Now.AddHours(-<%#test%>)
```

test from database = 100

So it's must be like:

```
DateTime.Now.AddHours(-100)
```

But compiler get error:

```
CS1040: Preprocessor directives must appear as the first non-whitespace character on a line
```

How can I fix it?

Test from public page load:

```
    OleDbConnection Connection;
    Connection = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0;Data Source=" +
               Server.MapPath("~/db.mdb"));
    OleDbCommand Command1, 
    Command1 = new OleDbCommand("SELECT FTPTARIHARALIGI FROM Table1 WHERE ID = 1", Connection);
    Connection.Open();
    int test = (int)Command1.ExecuteScalar();
```

I need to use this variable in other class(gridview row)

```
public void GridView2_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    DateTime dt;
    if (DateTime.TryParseExact(e.Row.Cells[2].Text, "yyyyMMddHHmm",
                              CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                              DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
    {
        if (dt <= DateTime.Now.AddHours(test * -1))
        {
            // ...
```

Comment: What is `-<%#test%>`?? If it's ASP.NET add that tag and show more context.

Comment: Asp.net, added tag, added more context.

Comment: It's still not clear where you use the code `DateTime.Now.AddHours(-<%#test%>)`

Comment: I use GridView2 RowDataBound. Added all code.

Comment: But where is the code that is still on the top: `DateTime.Now.AddHours(-<%#test%>)`? Now it seems that you are actually using `DateTime.Now.AddHours(test * -1)`. Also, if you initialize the **local variable** `test` from `Page_Load` you cannot access it from `RowDataBound`. Use a field/property instead.

Comment: I tried test * -1 too after Ehsan reply my question. Tried DateTime.Now.AddHours(-<%#test%>) too, i got CS1040 error.

Comment: problem is that test is local variable

Comment: How can I use this variable for my all class?

Comment: You have to create a property in your DB operation class or return it via a method whose return type is int, if it is in same class but different method then see my updated post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way if `test` is of type `int`:

```
DateTime.Now.AddHours(test * -1);
```

or:

```
DateTime.Now.AddHours(0 - test);
```

### UPDATE:

Your problem is `test` is a local variable in `Page_load` method.

Make it global, and declare it outside `Page_Load`:

```
YourClass
{
 int test = 0;

  PageLoad Method
  {

   // set test here
   test = (int)Command1.ExecuteScalar();
  }

  GirdDataRowBound Event
  {
    // use it here now accessible as it is global

   if (dt <= DateTime.Now.AddHours(test * -1))
  }

}
```

Comment: you can also just do `-test`

Comment: was not sure about it @musefan

Comment: Don't even need the `0`... `DateTime.Now.AddHours(-test);`

Comment: test variable in page load. I need to use other class and getting error CS0103: The name 'test' does not exist in the current context. Page load is public, also other class too. How can I use this variable on everywhere on my page?

Comment: But when I use like this, GridDataRowBound reading 0, not in pageload value. Did I missed something?

Comment: you need to debug it and check that is it setting some value in test and show your class relevant code the above code is not enough to see where is mistake

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `=`

Try:

```
DateTime.Now.AddHours(-<%=test%>)

<%# is a data binding syntax for use in databound controls.
<%= is a short cut for Response.Write.
<%@ is a directive to include a namespace, page directives, etc.
```